# ChoiceChip not expanding with IntrinsicWidth

Tags: flutter

I'm wondering why `ChoiceChip` is not expanding like `ElevatedButton` does.

Here is an example: ([look at dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2ab5870ce540baf58454490efdc05b6c))

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
          IntrinsicWidth(
              child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Larger Text'),
                onPressed: () {},
              )),
              Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Text'),
                onPressed: () {},
              )),
            ],
          )),
          IntrinsicWidth(
              child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const [
              Expanded(
                  child: ChoiceChip(
                label: Text('Larger Text'),
                selected: false,
              )),
              Expanded(
                  child: ChoiceChip(
                label: Text('Text'),
                selected: false,
              )),
            ],
          ))
        ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, let's start by enabling `Flutter Inspector`, we can see the second `IntrinsicWidth` width and its children don't fill their parent as the first one (two problems)

[image]

#### Solve 1st problem: IntrinsicWidth children don't fill their parent width

So, the problem is the size of the `2nd IntrinsicWidth`'s children is not wide/big enough so that it can be full of parent width. Try increasing its width manually by wrapping it in a `Container` with `double.infinity` width, like this:

```dart
ChoiceChip(
  label: Container(width: double.infinity, child: Text('Larger Text')),
  selected: false,
)
```

New result:

[image]

#### Solve 2nd problem: the 2nd `IntrinsicWidth` don't fill their parent width

Let's leave `Column` children can have the maximum width as it is (removing all `IntrinsicWidth` inside its children) and then wrap the `Column` by an `IntrinsicWidth`. Complete sample code:

Sample code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Larger Text'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Text'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ChoiceChip(
                  label: Container(width: double.infinity, child: Text('Larger Text')),
                  selected: false,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ChoiceChip(
                  label: Container(width: double.infinity, child: Text('Text')),
                  selected: false,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Little improvement: instead of using a Container, which gives me a warning, I've used this: SizedBox(width: double.infinity, child: Center(child: Text('Text')))

Answer (score 0):

Because under the hood the widgets are designed differently (that's why the names).

I haven't checked the code in detail (you can do that by ctrl + click on Widget Name).

But best guess, visual density is lower in chips for being compact and higher in buttons.

More on technical difference to understand which to use : [chips-vs-button](https://m3.material.io/components/chips/guidelines)

Comment: I'm pretty new to Flutter, can you please explain a bit more what is visual density about and why it should influence this case?

Comment: its just a property that adds constraints for padding vertically and/or horizontally.